# Set Notification on user selected time

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, timepicker

I want to set notification when user selects time from time picker. For this as I have searched I got to know should use calendar to set the time and alarm manager to set the alarm.

I have done accordingly. But the Notification dose not raise on the selected time.

Setting time on time picker's updateTime method.

```
 private void updateTime(int hour, int minute) {

    df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");

    if (timeType == 0) {

        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);

        datefrom = c.getTime();
        startTime = String.valueOf(datefrom);
        aTime = df.format(datefrom.getTime());
        showFromTime.setText(aTime);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(datefrom), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else if (timeType == 1) {

        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);

        dateto = c.getTime();
        endTime = String.valueOf(dateto);
        bTime = df.format(dateto.getTime());
        showToTime.setText(bTime);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(dateto), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    else if (timeType == 2)
    {
      //  c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
        c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
        notification = c.getTime();
        notificationTime = df.format(notification);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),notificationTime,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setAlarm(c);
    }
}
```

I have 3 time pickers in my activity so I have done accordingly.
Calendar instance I have called onCreate method.

setAlarm method

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetmCalen) {



    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),AddEventActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetmCalen.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "call alarmManager.setExact()",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Notification Set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Notification Receiver class:

```
public class NotificationReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {


private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
Notification myNotification;

EventTableHelper db;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Time is set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    Calendar c =Calendar.getInstance();

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            0,
            myIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("Event Time")
            .setContentText("Time")
            .setWhen(c.getTimeInMillis())
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_black_48dp)
            .build();
    Log.i("Notify","Notification");
    notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
}
```

}

Manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout" >


    <permission
        android:name="com.example.siddhi.go_jek.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AddEventActivity" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
                </action>
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What am I missing in all this?

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences on your activity to save the selected time

```
    SharedPrefereces pref = getSharedPreferences("com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
    edit.putInt("startTime", startTime);
    edit.commit();
```

Then load your SharedPreferences on your Service

```
SharedPrefereces pref = getSharedPreferences("com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

On your onReceive method, check if SharedPreferences saved time equals current time:

```
String startTime=pref.getString("startTime");
Calendar currentDate = c.getInstance();
String currentTime = String.valueOf(c.getTime());
if(currentTime.equalsIgnoreCase(startTime))
{
 myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle("Event Time")
        .setContentText("Time")
        .setWhen(c.getTimeInMillis())
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_black_48dp)
        .build();
}
```